# TestNG Not Running Parallel Methods

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm using testNG to run some Selenium tests in parallel, my suite.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="20" name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test name="Test1" group-by-instances="true" junit="true">
   <classes>
      <class name="uk.co.Pack1"/>
      <class name="uk.co.Pack2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

`Pack1` contains 2 tests and `Pack2` contains 1 test so using `parallel="methods"` I would expect 3 Chrome browsers to appear but only one does.

If I write each class with its methods in seperate tests, each with a single method specified, then set `parallel="tests"` it works - however duplicating code like that is not something I like neither best practice.

Can anyone help to why this may be?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Post your code of chromedriver instantiation. Even if you are initializing thrice, but the instance is same then things get overwritten.
2. Checking parallelism better way would be to add a sysout with Thread.currentthread.getId.  This way you can pinpoint whether the issue is with parallelism or code.

Comment: Also parallel = methods is correct for what you want to achieve.  I see junit=true in test tag.  Is that required.  And group-by-instances is not required in the scenario you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

i am a beginner and I spent more than 3 hours,

every time i executed it went fine, but not with one scenario.

is your both classes have same parent class? and are you initiating your "driver" in parent class? and using the same driver instance for your child classes?

When i do the above, it invoked the same browser to run all tests, though 3 threads were running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run methods parallel then you have to create multiple web driver session to handle every thread

You can find solution here

https://github.com/PatilRohit/WebDriverParallelService/

Which solve your sync issue for methods in parallel run.

Answer (score -1):

Try by using `parallel="tests"` instead of "methods". It will run all your tests parallelly

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that but naturally wouldn't expect (and neither does it) work as I only have one test with 2 classes in there.

Comment: Can you please post sample code snippet of your tests and classes?

Comment: They are literally basic methods - I used literally same as here:
http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/parallel-execution-of-test-methods-in-testng

Comment: Do you initialize chromedriver in each method undet @Test annotation?

Comment: Yep - every test has @Test

Comment: parallel=tests works for test tags in xml and not methods.  For his req, parallel=methods is correct.